# Download US census data profiles?

Tags: data, api, census, united-states, tiger

US census summary file information is available on the census ftp server: `ftp2.census.gov/acs2013_5yr` but I can't seem to find the data profiles information anywhere.

The only source appears to be the census data api ([census.gov](http://www.census.gov/data/developers/data-sets/acs-survey-5-year-data.html) and [api.census.gov](http://api.census.gov/data/2013/acs5/profile/variables.html)).

Is there any place you can download this raw data or is this API the only source? I've scoured the census site and I hope I'm not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The demographic profile tables (DP02, DP03, DP04, DP05) are extracts from the more detailed ones, so I'm not sure they would be available on the ftp server (since all the data is there in the full tables by default).

Another option would be to look at the Missouri Census Data Center's Uexplore/Dexter tools here:

http://mcdc.missouri.edu/applications/uexplore.shtml

They provide their own api that includes summary profiles that are similar to the DP tables, and it looks like you can download them en masse.